# Volume with MonteCarlo

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

I'm asked to find the volume of a given bounded solid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by MonteCarlo means: since it is contained in a prism, I generate random points in the prism and see what proportion of them lie inside my solid. The more points I have, the more precision I'll get.

The problem is I'm asked to give an error estimation as a function of the number of points $n$. I know there´s an easy expression when evaluating integrals using MonteCarlo methods, but can't find the way to give the analogue here. It may be related, but I'm not sure.

Either a derivation of the seeked expression or a hint to find the analogy will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the number of points that fall inside the solid (or, equivalently, the estimated volume) is a random variable. Ask yourself which distribution will it have, its mean and variance...

Comment: You need to know basic probability theory to show that.

Comment: The volume can be expressed as an integral, namely, as the integral of the function that is $1$ on your solid and $0$ elsewhere.